# Magento Language translation For Registration Page only

Tags: php, magento

In my project in magento i want to translate language into Mexican,vietnamise and american for registration page.I want to give option in registration page for language translate when i click language it have to translate language only for registration page only not for whole site.Please share your suggestion regarding this.Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this manually....first of all check for current module, controller and action, if it is for registration then change its langauge else set it to default...something like this :

```
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'customer' &&  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'account' && Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'create')
{
 Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale($local)->init('frontend', true);
}
else
{
 Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale($default_local)->init('frontend', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a prefix to your translation strings inside a theme's translate.csv file so that this translation will only be used in a single module. Though in the case of your requirements it will translate every thing in `Mage_Customer`.

```
"Mage_Customer::Base string","Translated String"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try inline translation feature of Magento. Login to admin panel and navigate to System -> Configuration. Then in Advanced group click on Developer and in Translate Inline section choose Yes for Enabled for Frontend and click Save Config. Now navigate to your page and you can translate particular text from there.